# Where should I ask a question about how to interpret a chart of greenhouse gases?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am studying for a test for university access in Sweden. The limited amount of spots in university program is assigned to who scored best.

I have the list of correct answers but I cannot figure out why the solution for a specific exercise is correct (and my answer was wrong). The question is about a chart of greenhouse gases.

I went through the list of Stack Exchange sites but I could not find an obvious fit. Do you think there is one where my question could be on topic?

**Update**

If you are curious, here are the questions I asked based on the answers here. Both communities did not reject my question, which was slightly better received on Cross Validated.

Earth Science: [How to interpret correctly this chart about nitrogen oxide?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/18847/how-to-interpret-correctly-this-chart-about-nitrogen-oxide)

Cross Validated: [How to interpret correctly this chart about nitrogen oxide?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443086/how-to-interpret-correctly-this-chart-about-nitrogen-oxide/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a general question on chart interpretation, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), whose scope includes data visualization.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is about greenhouse gases, so I think [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) is the right site. They have [quite a few questions](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouse-gases) about greenhouse gases. The fact that you encountered this question in a test isn't particularly relevant in determining the correct site; it's what we call *meta* information.

Note that for a good question, you'd probably need to include the chart, which might not be allowed because of licensing.

Comment: Thank you! The question is more about how to interpret correctly a question about a chart. I hope the Earth Science folk will welcome me!

Comment: If something is licensed and the license prohibits reproduction, one can still link to the material, describe it or give the data points (most likely only the layout is copyrighted, not the data itself).

Comment: Software like the R package [digitize](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digitize/index.html) can help to extract data from images.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are studying for “Hogskoleorovet”. The part of the test you referr to is only about interpreting the charts, not about domain knowledge. So forget all your knowledge of the area and focus only on the information in the test. All needed information is in the test.

Comment: Yes, it is the högskoleprovet. But it did help me asking on Cross Validated.